# Install-Module not available - not recognized as a name of a cmdlet

Tags: powershell, powershell-7.0

I'm trying to take advantage of the PowerShell Gallery which requires Install-Module. For some reason I cannot get this to work on any computer I have access to:

```
Install-Module: The term 'Install-Module' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
```

I tried this on a Windows 8.1, Windows 10 and even installed PowerShell 7.1 on the Windows 10 computer. I see that a lot of people have this issue, but other than installing WMF (which seems to already be included with Win10) I don't see any useful suggestions.

I don't have a lot of experience with PowerShell, and definitely not managing it, so I'm curious if anybody has an idea as to why this is not working.

**Edit 1:**
I seem to have the `PowerShellGet` module in the following directories:

```
C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules
C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\Modules
```

and the `$env:PSModulePath` variables contains `C:\Program Files\PowerShell\Modules;c:\program files\powershell\7\Modules;C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules`

**Edit 2:**
This may be related to the `__PSLockDownPolicy` environment variable, that was set to `4` on all of the affected computers. I was able to figure this out by attempting to manually load the `PowerShellGet` module, which yielded an error that hinted at this.

After removing that environment variable, it seems to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you've discovered yourself, it was the presence of **machine-level environment variable `__PSLockDownPolicy`** that prevented `Install-Module` from running (see below for general prerequisites).

This ***undocumented* environment variable**, effective on **Windows only**,  is for security reasons only respected if defined at the *machine* level *via the registry* (rather than as a *per-user* or process-specific variable) and **can be used to restrict what is allowed in a PowerShell session**.

Values `4` through `7` result in PowerShell operating in ***constrained* language mode, where only a handful of pre-approved .NET types may be used**, which as a result prevents the `PowerShellGet` module that contains the `Install-Module` from loading  - see the conceptual [about_Language Modes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_language_modes) help topic.

You can check what language mode is in effect in a given session by executing `$ExecutionContext.SessionState.LanguageMode`; in constrained mode, the result is `ConstrainedLanguage`; `FullLanguage` indicates that *no* language restrictions are in place.

Looking at PowerShell's source code, the fact that this variable is checked inside a method named [`GetDebugLockdownPolicy()`](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/0fffdf58aba6f6f4380714bfb6b047f8ed4d9458/src/System.Management.Automation/security/wldpNativeMethods.cs#L375) suggests that it **isn't officially supported**.

For more information, see [this archived blog post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/kfalde/pslockdownpolicy-and-powershell-constrained-language-mode).

The **simplest way to remove this restriction** is to *delete* the environment variable, by **running the following from an *elevated* PowerShell prompt**:

```
Remove-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment' __PSLockdownPolicy
```

---

**One mystery remains**:

As you state, importing the `PowerShellGet` module *explicitly*, with `Import-Module PowerShellGet` showed you that the real problem was *not* that the `Install-Module` command *didn't exist*, but that its *enclosing module failed to load*.

Doing so revealed that yet *another* module was the problem, namely the `PackageManagement` module that `PowerShellGet` depends on; `Import-Module PackageManagement` finally reveals: `Cannot set property. Property setting is supported only on core types in this language mode`, which implies that the (constrained) language mode was the problem.

The mystery is the error message reported in your question: `Install-Module: The term 'Install-Module' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.`

I see a *different* error message, both in Windows PowerShell 5.1 and PowerShell (Core) 7.1.2, when the constrained language mode is in effect, i.e. when  `$ExecutionContext.SessionState.LanguageMode` reports `ConstrainedLanguage`:

`Install-Module: The 'Install-Module' command was found in the module 'PowerShellGet', but the module could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module PowerShellGet'.`

This error message makes it more obvious what the problem is, and would probably have led to a faster diagnosis.

---

The following contains *general* information that is unrelated to the above:

**Installing / troubleshooting of the `PowerShellGet` module that provides the `Install-Module` command:**

[`Install-Module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/PowershellGet/Install-Module) is a (function-based) cmdlet that comes with Windows PowerShell 5.0 and 5.1 as well as all versions of PowerShell (Core) (v6+), as part of the `PowerShellGet` module.

If your computers *do* meet these criteria, the implication is that your PowerShell installation has been corrupted in one or both of the following ways:

- The `PowerShell` get module was removed (or renamed) from its default location
  (`C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet` in Windows PowerShell,
  `C:\Program Files\Powershell\7\Modules\PowerShellGet` in PowerShell (Core) 7.x, on Windows).

  - Either reinstall PowerShell or try the manual installation instructions linked to below.
- The `$env:PSModulePath` environment variable is missing an entry for the *parent* directory of the respective default location (that is,
  `C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules` /
  `C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\Modules`). Without this entry, PowerShell cannot find the `PowerShellGet` module (by *name only*).

  - Manually update the machine-level definition of environment variable `PSModulePath` via `sysdm.cpl`, tab `Advanced`, button `Environment Variables...` to include the applicable directory.

If your computers do *not* meet these criteria, you have two choices:

- If you can, [upgrade the Windows PowerShell version to v5.1](http://aka.ms/wmf5download) or switch to [PowerShell (Core)](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell#get-powershell).
- Alternatively - if your Windows PowerShell version is 3 or 4 - install `PowerShellGet` *manually*, as per the [official instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/gallery/install-on-older-systems).

  - Note: You may have to have access to at least *one* computer that already has a functioning copy of `PowerShellGet` to source the manual installation from.

Comment: I'm not sure why I'm getting a different error message, but it's the one I've been getting on all machines.